# how can i solve error ''float' object is not iterable'

Tags: python, pandas, loops, tuples, geopy

im new at python, and try to categorize places an df1 by distance to places in df2, but something gonna wrong

i have 2 dataframes whith coordinate of places

```
import pandas as pd
import geopy.distance

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 55.88, 37.48],
                   ['b', 55.88, 37.53],
                   ['c', 55.89, 37.45]],
                   columns=['name', 'lat', 'lng']

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['f', 55.81, 37.12],
                   ['g', 55.79, 37.23],
                   ['h', 55.23, 37.21]],
                   columns=['name', 'lat', 'lng']
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

df1

| name | lat | lng |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 55.88 | 37.48 |
| b | 55.88 | 37.53 |
| c | 55.89 | 37.45 |

df2

| name | lat | lng |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f | 55.81 | 37.12 |
| g | 55.79 | 37.23 |
| h | 55.23 | 37.21 |

so, i try to calculate distance between a and f,g,h and if distance to one of this place less than 1000m, append category
"close" and else category 'far', and do it for each name in df1

i want this df

print(df1)

| name | lat | lng | dist_to_palce |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 55.88 | 37.48 | far |
| b | 55.88 | 37.53 | close |
| c | 55.89 | 37.45 | far |

i try this construction

```
def dist(df1):
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        for j in range(len(df2)):
            if geopy.distance.geodesic(
                tuple(data[['lat','lng']].iloc[i]),
                tuple(metro[['lat','lng']].iloc[j])).m <1000:
                    return 'close'
            else: return 'far'


 df1['dist_to_place'] = df1.apply(dist, axis=1)
```

but i got error 'float' object is not iterable

help me please :C

**solution**

```py
def dist(df1_row):        
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if geopy.distance.geodesic(
            tuple(df1_row[['lat','lng']]),
            tuple(df2[['lat','lng']].iloc[j])).m <1000:
                return 'close'
    return 'far'


df1['dist_to_place'] = df1.apply(dist, axis=1)
```

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that generates your error message with a stack trace. I should be able to copy your code with no changes or additions that can be executed and generates the same error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopy.distance

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b'],'lat':[56.34, 76.56], 'lng':[23.42, 45.34]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['f', 'g'],'lat':[56.45, 76.55], 'lng':[27.42, 40.34]})

def dist(df1_row):        
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if geopy.distance.geodesic(
            tuple(df1_row[['lat','lng']]),
            tuple(df2[['lat','lng']].iloc[j])).m <1000:
                return 'close'
    return 'far'


df1['dist_to_place'] = df1.apply(dist, axis=1)
```

1. when you use apply, row is given to your function, not the whole dataframe
2. you need to return `far` after the cycle, not inside

Comment: Thank you very much! Your decision helped and everything worked out!
I have a question about optimizing the function

I have 8500 rows in the first table, and 320 in the second.
The execution time of the function for these two tables took 19 minutes 43 seconds. Is it possible to optimize the execution time of the function?

Comment: @ивансинев , please check geopandas and data join. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html it may help you to avoid nested loop of size 8500 * 320

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you are returning a string value 'close' or 'far' from the dist function and trying to assign it to the entire row of the df1 dataframe using df1.apply(dist, axis=1). Instead of returning a string, you should create a list of values with length equal to the number of rows in df1, and then assign the list to a new column in df1.

```
import geopy.distance

def dist(row):
    result = []
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if geopy.distance.geodesic(
            (row['lat'], row['lng']),
            (df2.loc[j, 'lat'], df2.loc[j, 'lng'])).m < 1000:
                result.append('close')
        else: result.append('far')
    return result
```

df1['dist_to_place'] = df1.apply(dist, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[0])

above code calculates the distance between each place in df1 and all the places in df2, but only the first occurrence of 'close' or 'far' is returned and assigned to the new column in df1.